# Displaying wrong data passed by std::thread function.

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using C++ threading. I want to display every row from SQL database pass to the Thread function and display it. My problem is, the displayed data is somewhat redundant if I'll pass it for every Thread array. Why am I displaying wrong data?

```
void callThread(char fname[], int age, int i) {
    std::cout << "\tThread : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << fname << age << std::endl;
}


/*Inside main function*/
int i = 0;
int age;
char fname[20];

    while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_CHAR, fname, sizeof(fname), NULL);
        SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 2, SQL_C_ULONG, &age, sizeof(age), NULL);

        //display query result
        //std::cout << "\nQuery Result:\n\n";
        //std::cout << fname << age << std::endl;

            threadArray[i] = std::thread(callThread, fname, age, i);
            threadArray[i].detach();

        i++;
        printf("\n Counter: %d\n",i);
    }
```

**Database Content:**
[image]

**Sample Output:**
    `Katrina 23`
    `Katrina 22`

**Desired Output**
    `James 23`
    `Katrina 22`

Comment: You pass the same `fname[]` character array to every thread instance.  Don't be surprised when the next iteration of the loop overwrites it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a **race condition**: `fname` is an array, into which you read the first name. When you pass it to the thread, all you *really* pass is a pointer to the first element in memory. The next value is read, overwriting the name in that array - and the other thread still uses the same memory location.

The solution is to copy the string before you pass it to the other thread, preferably via `std::string`:

```
void callThread(std::string fname, int age, int i) {
    std::cout << "\tThread : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << fname << age << std::endl;
}

// ...

threadArray[i] = std::thread(callThread, std::string(fname), age, i);
```

Comment: I got error says, `Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: You likely forgot to `#include <string>`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik +1. Yeah. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of a data race. You have the thread read the contents of `fname` at the same time `main` writes to it.

Comment: Should I put locker?